# couldn't compile a logistic regression code in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have run this code on mat lab.....

```
function [store,temp] = LR( X,y )
store=zeros(10,10);
indices = crossvalind('Kfold',y,10);
    for i = 1:10
        test = (indices == i); train = ~test;
        [b,dev,stats] = glmfit(X(train,:),y(train),'binomial','logit');        
        temp= glmval(b,X(test,:),'logit');
        store(:,i)=temp; 
    end

end
```

but I'm getting an error
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
Error in LR (line 8)
        store(:,i)=temp;

please help

Comment: What size is temp? Put in `size(temp)` on the line before `store(:,i)=temp;`, that will tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: Why is this tagged SVM? Don't just tag for the sake of it. Also are you sure you didn't need to add a column of ones to your `X` matrix? Lastly please provide the dimensions for `X` and `y` at the very least, however a full description of what you think your code is doing would be better

Answer (score 0):

Check the dimension of `store(:,i)` and `temp`. Maybe you need to transpose the `temp` with `temp'` or modify `store(:,i)` to `store(i,:)`.